# Access 2013 To Link All Local Tables To Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2013

I have roughly 75 local tables in an Access 2013 database, that I need to get into SQL Server 2008 R2.  The export wizard or upsize wizard does not work for me, the only process I have found that works is to export the table to .csv then import the .csv into SQL Server.  I also do it this way so that I do not have to set-up a DSN on my computer.  I would rather not do that will all 75 tables, so I was wondering if there was a VBA way of Exporting Local Access 2013 tables To SQL Server with no DSN set-up?

**EDIT**
1) And there is no linked server between my server and access (I am not a sys admin to add) so using the Openrowset is not an option

2) I have the Access 2007 Database Engine installed on my system already.

Comment: You could obviously script something in VBA using ADO, but I'm curious why the wizards aren't working.

Comment: You might be better to start from SSMS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Comment: @Comintern - I know how to script from SQL To Access, but not the other way.  Any links or tips on how to start the other way around?

Comment: @Fionnuala - if I do access database engine or jet database engine it only shows .mdb.  If I change it to all files to select my accdb then the error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

What you need it the SQL Server Migration Assistant.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt613434.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The Migration Assistant was removed from Access 2013.

Comment: The Migration Assistant is a separate utility and NOT part of Access. It is the upsizing wizard that was removed from Access. Follow the link that I posted.

Comment: I did, when trying to download the SQL Server Migration Assistant from that link http://aka.ms/ssmaforaccess I just get a spinning circle.

Comment: It should lead you here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53121

Comment: A spinning circle doesn't equate to 'removed from Access 2013'. The link I posted contains the information on SSMA and includes the same download link that Andre posted. Try the download link above or with a different browser.